# Android: TabLayout indocator hanging between tabs

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tablayout

I'm using android support library (23.1.1) to create a tab layout. I followed the tutorial [here](http://slidenerd.com/2015/07/22/android-design-support-library/), it uses AppCompatActivity. The problem is that the indicator of the TabLayout is handing between the two tabs and not moving smoothly when swiping. When searching for a solution I found similar problem that the indicator bounces between tabs, and its solution was to use newer version of the library. I'm using the latest version and facing this problem.

[image: Here is an image]

Comment: Use the SlidingTabLayout and SlidingTabStrip provided by Google. https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java  and also use tabs.setDistributeEvenly() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the SlidingTabStrip file here - https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java

you can also follow this tutorial on Android4Devs - http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html to get started

Comment: Is it possible to set the middle tab as default if I have 3 tabs when the application starts?

Comment: **yes it is**.. Since you have 3 tabs, Tab 1 is index 0 and Tab 2 which is the middle will be index 1. `ViewPager pager;   pager.setCurrentItem(1, true);` where parameter 1 is the index you want to set while parameter 2 is to enable smooth-scroll