# Android: SlidingTabLayout icon size, color, alignment, and default tab

Tags: android

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) to create a SlidingTabLayout. It worked fine, but I want to customize it to add icons instead of text. I used the following code which I found in a question:

Adapter.java

```
private int[] imageResId = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_all,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_fav,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_profile
    };
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {           
        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);            
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return sb;
    }
```

custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="16dp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);
mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
```

But I still need to know the following:

- How to change icons color and what sizes should the icons be?
- How to align the icons in the middle of the tab?
- How to set the middle tab as default?

Answer (score 0):

try this in on create :  `tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setIconForTabs(tabLayout);`
and this 2 methods:

```
public int getIconsForTabs(int i) {
    int[] imageResId = {
            R.drawable.ic_action_action_event,
            R.drawable.ic_action_av_my_library_books,
            R.drawable.ic_action_maps_location_history,
            R.drawable.ic_action_content_report
    };
    return imageResId[i];
}




}
private void setIconForTabs(TabLayout tabLayout) {
    Drawable drawable;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, getIconsForTabs(i));
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.yourColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(drawable);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setText("");
    }

}
```

and the xml `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

you need to use the support design library

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was using the support library and I had a bug [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006230/android-tablayout-indocator-hanging-between-tabs/34006894#34006894)